# Caller cannot hear me. Microphone works

Tags: calls, microphone

People over phone calls or whatsapp calls cannot hear me, or barely, if I shout out loud.

But the microphone works. I can make records and hear them from far.

Already set to max at Settings > Sound And Notifications > Acessories Configuration

Xperia Z3 d6633

Android M 6.0.2

Comment: This happened to be the case with my Nexus 6 too. But the other party could hear me if I turned on loudspeaker. Is it also the same in your case?

Comment: Indeed. Tested on whatsapp. It works. Probably does for calls. Now the problem is I cannot answer in public this way.